# Animation not included in rendered video

Tags: rendering, animation

Animation: https://gyazo.com/3e56fd22fe83be0c86af384dced417b7

The problems is that when I try to render the video it just shows the sphere which can be seen in the right part of the image, but nothing of the actual fluids I made. Any ideas?

I've checked several posts with similar issues, but with no luck.

My .blend file (uploaded to WeTransfer): https://we.tl/t-VbOcBdUbsq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press this button here:

[image]

and then turn render on for your fluid...and it works like a charm! ;)

[image]